# How to get modifier keys now that `KeyboardInput.modifiers` is deprecated?

Tags: rust, event-handling, keyboard-events

The Rust library [winit](https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit/) has `DeviceEvent`s and `WindowEvent`s.

Both can detect keyboard input.  I wish to use `DeviceEvent`s because I am working on a window manager which will be running even when there are no application windows.

I need to be able to detect the modifier keys (Ctrl, Alt, Win, Shift).

However, [KeyboardInput.modifiers has been deprecated](https://docs.rs/winit/0.22.1/winit/event/struct.KeyboardInput.html) in favour of [WindowEvent::ModifiersChanged](https://docs.rs/winit/0.22.1/winit/event/enum.WindowEvent.html#variant.ModifiersChanged)

If I don't have a window, is there a way of detecting the modifiers without using the deprecated method from `DeviceEvent`?